# Исключение: ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: .net, c++-cli

В программе на С++/CLI нужно по нажатию кнопки из одной формы открыть другую. Однако во время выполнения кода выскакивает ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Что с этим можно сделать?

Вот код обработчика события:

```
private: System::Void cmd_Activate_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Hide();
    Application::OpenForms["frm_Activate1"]->Show();

}
```

Comment: Это значит, что у вас нет формы с именем frm_Activate1.

Comment: Openforms был бы нужен, если выполнима уже открыта и то там нужен не show. Вам же нужно вызвать конструктор форму, и потом show или showdialog

Comment: @ 4per
Спасибо! Попробую покопаться. Меня только смущает, что в других местах программы эти операторы работают. Может где-то есть конструктор, но я про него забыл. Может быть такое, что без конструктора операторы сработают?

Comment: Нашел ошибку, из-за которой конструктор не хотел работать, поэтому и попытки использовать код, показанный в обработчике событий, тоже не удавались. Она в корректности записи названия формы в ее коде.